# Uncaught ReferenceError: add_chamber is not defined

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

This is my view file in my codeigniter project.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // find the input fields and apply the time select to them.
            $('#sample1 input').ptTimeSelect();
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

function add_chamber() {

    $.ajax({
      url: "<? echo base_url("doctormain/add_chamber");?>",
        type: "POST",
     data: {
            name :  $("input#name").val()
            address :  $("input#address").val()
            city :  $("input#city").val()
            locality :  $("input#locality").val()
            State: :  $("input#state").val()
            landline :  $("input#landline").val()
            mobile :  $("input#mobile").val()
            email :  $("input#email").val()
            days :  $("input#mon").val()+$("input#tue").val()+$("input#wed").val()+$("input#thur").val()+$("input#fri").val()+$("input#sat").val()+$("input#sun").val()
            start :  $("input#start").val()
            end :  $("input#end").val()
            comments :  $("input#comments").val()

                    }
    })
   .success (function(response) { $('#sucess').html(response)})
    .error   (function()     { alert("Error")   ; });

}
</script>


<div class="content">
<div class="content-left">
<div  class="row1">
<h2>Welcome <? echo $username ?></h2>
<h1> Add Chamber </h1>
<h2><div id="sucess"></div></h2>



   <?php echo form_open_multipart('doctormain/add_chamber');?>

      <table width="100%">

<tr><td> Name:</td><td> <input name="name" type="text" id="name"></td></tr>
<tr><td> Address:</td><td>  <input name="address" type="text" id="address"></td></tr>
<tr><td> City:</td><td>  <input name="city" type="text" id="city"></td></tr>
<tr><td> Locality:</td><td> <input name="locality" type="text" id="locality"></td></tr>
<tr><td> State:</td><td>  <input name="state" type="text" id="state"></td></tr>
<tr><td> Landline:</td><td>  <input name="landline" type="text" id="landline"></td></tr>
<tr><td> Mobile:</td><td>  <input name="mobile" type="text" id="mobile"></td></tr>
<tr><td> Email:</td><td>  <input name="email" type="text" id="email"></td></tr>
<tr>
  <td> Days Of Availability:</td><td>
  Mon:<input name="mon" type="checkbox" id="mon" value="1" checked>
  Tue:<input name="tue" type="checkbox" id="tue" value="2"  checked>
  Wed:<input name="wed" type="checkbox" id="wed" value="3" checked>
  Thur:<input name="thur" type="checkbox" id="thur" value="4" checked>
  Fri:<input name="fri" type="checkbox" id="fri" value="5" checked>
  Sat:<input name="sat" type="checkbox"  id="sat" value="6" checked>
  Sun:<input name="sun" type="checkbox" id="sun" value="7" checked>
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td> Time Of Availability</td><td>

  <div id="sample1" class="ui-widget-content" style="padding: .5em;">
        <p>
            <label>Start</label>
            <input name="s1Time2" id="start" value="" /> 
            <label>End</label>
            <input name="s1Time2" id="end" value="" />
        </p>
        </div>



  </td></tr>
<tr><td> Comments:</td><td> <input name="comments" type="testbox" id="comments" ></td></tr>

<tr><td> </td><td> <input name="submit" id="submit" class="button" type="button" value="Save" onclick="add_chamber()">
</td></tr>
<? echo form_close();?>
      </table>

   <div id="results">
   </div>
   </div>


</div>

<div class="content-right">
<div class="mainmenu">
<h2 class="sidebar1">My Menu</h2>
<p><ul>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 9</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 10</a></li>
</ul></p>
</div>



</div>
</div>
```

But when i click save to do the required job of database entry i give me an error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: add_chamber is not defined

I cannot find where is the fault can anyone help me regarding this error. Is there anything regarding to scope or something else i cannot point out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax call is all wrong.

Try

```
$.ajax({
 url : url,
 success : function(response){  },
 error   : function(){  }
});


function add_chamber()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "<? echo base_url("doctormain/add_chamber");?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: 
        {
            name :  $("input#name").val(),
            address :  $("input#address").val(),
            city :  $("input#city").val(),
            locality :  $("input#locality").val(),
            State: :  $("input#state").val(),
            landline :  $("input#landline").val(),
            mobile :  $("input#mobile").val(),
            email :  $("input#email").val(),
            days :  $("input#mon").val()+$("input#tue").val()+$("input#wed").val()+$("input#thur").val()+$("input#fri").val()+$("input#sat").val()+$("input#sun").val(),
            start :  $("input#start").val(),
            end :  $("input#end").val(),
            comments :  $("input#comments").val()
        },
        success (function(response) { $('#sucess').html(response)}),
        error   (function()     { alert("Error"); }
    });
}
```

Comment: r u sure this will work ? because as in your code you have not added , after  val() like ->   name :$("input#name").val()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
url: '<? echo base_url("doctormain/add_chamber");?>'
```

Answer (score 0):

escape `"`

```
url: "<? echo base_url(\"doctormain/add_chamber\");?>",
```

OR

```
url: "<? echo base_url('doctormain/add_chamber');?>",
```

Answer (score 0):

You have error in concatanation & in order of functions in ajax replace your function by:

```
 function add_chamber() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<? echo base_url("doctormain/add_chamber"); ?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            name :  $("input#name").val(),
            address :  $("input#address").val(),
            city :  $("input#city").val(),
            locality :  $("input#locality").val(),
            State:$("input#state").val(),
            landline :  $("input#landline").val(),
            mobile :  $("input#mobile").val(),
            email :  $("input#email").val(),
            days :  $("input#mon").val() +$("input#tue").val()+$("input#wed").val()+$("input#thur").val()+$("input#fri").val()+$("input#sat").val()+$("input#sun").val(),
            start :  $("input#start").val(),
            end :  $("input#end").val(),
            comments :  $("input#comments").val()
        },
        success :function(response) {
            $('#sucess').html(response)
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

some syntax errors in your function , please replace this code

function add_chamber() {

```
$.ajax({
  url: "<? echo base_url('doctormain/add_chamber');?>",
    type: "POST",
 data: {
        name :  $("input#name").val(),
        address :  $("input#address").val(),
        city :  $("input#city").val(),
        locality :  $("input#locality").val(),
        State:   $("input#state").val(),
        landline :  $("input#landline").val(),
        mobile :  $("input#mobile").val(),
        email :  $("input#email").val(),
        days :  $("input#mon").val()+$("input#tue").val()+$("input#wed").val()+$("input#thur").val()+$("input#fri").val()+$("input#sat").val()+$("input#sun").val(),
        start :  $("input#start").val(),
        end :  $("input#end").val(),
        comments :  $("input#comments").val()

                }
})
```

.success (function(response) { $('#sucess').html(response)})
    .error   (function()     { alert("Error")   ; });

}